# How do I emit xml without the JSON escapsulation from Loopback

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using Strongloop's loopback product.  Within a remote method of a model, I need to generate an RSS feed.  The "rss" node.js package is what I am using - does all that I need.  However, if I return the XML to the remote method callback, the XML is then encapsulated in JSON before being passed to the REST API client (after thinking about it, its expected behavior...).

Is there a way to prevent this?  Note I dont want XML in XML either; just want to be able to return the raw XML from my code without further processing.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify the response using the context object:

```
{
  arg: 'custom',
  type: 'number',
  http: function(ctx) {
    return ctx.res.set('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
  }
}
```

See http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/Remote+methods